# @OneToMany in abstract class generates unusable schema

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have the following model classes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public abstract class BasePage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name="locale")
    private Map<String, Localized> text = new HashMap<String, Localized>();

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name="locale")
    private Map<String, Localized> title = new HashMap<String, Localized>();

    // ....
}

@Entity
public class Localized {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String locale;

    @Lob
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
    private String text;

    @Lob
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
    private String synopsis;

    // ....
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("FLATPAGE")
public class FlatPage {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("INSTITUTION")
public class Institution {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name="locale")
    private Map<String, Localized> contact;
}
```

So far so good, I have a small Entity class to hold localized (HTML) strings and an abstract class that is the base for specific types of nodes/articles in my application.
The SQL that is generated for the entities looks good, however I have a problem with the table that maps `BasePage` entities to `Localized` entities.

With Hibernate (4.3.4) and PostgreSQL (9.1), the following schema is generated:

```
CREATE TABLE basepage_localized
(
    basepage_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    contact_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    synopsis_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    text_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( basepage_id, synopsis_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( basepage_id ) REFERENCES basepage ( id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( text_id ) REFERENCES localized ( id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( contact_id ) REFERENCES localized ( id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( synopsis_id ) REFERENCES localized ( id )
);
```

The problem is that I can not create `FlatPage` entities, since `contact_id` has a `NOT NULL` constraint. I suspect there might be more problems with my schema, but that is the one that I currently struggle with....

Comment: What type of Inheritance strategy are your using ? From this code it seems if would use the default strategy SINGLE_TABLE. If so you have n't defined any discriminators ?

Comment: It is indeed single table inheritance. You are right about the discriminators, I must have forgotten those when dumbing down my example entities... I added them now. The problem still persists, though :-/